# Unhandled exception when firing WinRT 8.1 WebView ScriptNotify

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, caliburn.micro, windows-8.1

I'm trying to create an MVVM Caliburn-based WinRT 8.1 app (I know that CM won't be perfectly compatible with 8.1 until version 2.0 is out, but the error does not seem to be related, as it is raised also when the handler is placed in the view code behind). One of its views contains a *WebView* control, whose content is set via *NavigateToString* (HTML contents come from app's installed assets). The HTML loaded into this control includes several hyperlinks, most of them representing cross-references to other asset-based HTML content. So when users click the link I want to override the standard navigation action, get my viewmodel notified, and let it load another HTML content from the app assets.

Here is what I did, following the post [Open links in external browser in WebView (WinRT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703698/open-links-in-external-browser-in-webview-winrt):

1. in the XAML code, I added to the WebView control an attribute for attaching the ScriptNotify event to my VM: `cal:Message.Attach="[Event ScriptNotify] = [Action GetFromLink($eventArgs)]"` (see https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions).
2. in my VM, the method signature is `public void GetFromLink(NotifyEventArgs e)`.
3. whenever my VM loads some HTML into the WebView, it first injects a script in the HTML head which replaces the click handler of each anchor representing a cross-reference (all these anchors are marked by a `class="xref"` attribute). This script is hold in a constant in my VM:

`private const string SCRIPT = "for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {" +
    "var className = document.links[i].getAttribute(\"class\");" +
    "if (className && className === \"xfer\") {" +
    "document.links[i].onclick = function() {" +
    "window.external.notify('url:' + this.href);" +
    "return false;" +
    "}}}";`

Now, when I launch the app, load an item containing one of these xref's and click on it, I get an **unhandled exception** telling me that **"navCancelInit is undefined"**. I suppose this error is surfacing from JS code, but I cannot see where and how this function should be defined.

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227713, I do not need any additional step for *ScriptNotify* when HTML has been loaded via *NavigateToString*. Could anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from a MS guy about this, so credit is not mine for this answer: it is a timing issue. I must ensure that the page has fully loaded before running the script which changes the DOM; pretty simple, if you think. Just moving the script at the end of the page, or wrapping it in an onload handler, should make the trick. Hope this can save some hair-pulling to others!

Answer (score 0):

If you listen to this event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.domcontentloaded.aspx WebView.DOMContentLoaded event, All of the script should be loaded in the WebView and you should be able to access and execute, if you are trying to do this before the scripts won't be loaded.