# Hyperlink click is not firing

Tags: javascript, events, hyperlink, click

I'd like to catch click on hyperlink with JavaScript. I used this code :

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) { 
    document.links[i].onclick = function() { 
           doSomething();       
        } 
    }
```

On normal hyperlink `<a href="index.html">Home</a>` everything works but on link to pdf file

```
<a href="tmp.pdf">tmp.pdf</a>
```

action `doSomething();` is not called. My page is redirected to tmp.pdf without firing click event. I don't have a idea why.

Can you advise me what is problem. I'd like to avoid jQuery.

Comment: What do you mean by "Only pdf file is opened in browser"?

Comment: that my page is redirecting to tmp.pdf without firing click event

Comment: When/where is the for loop used?

Comment: Try switching document.links to `document.getElementByTagName("a")`

Comment: document.links contains all hyperlinks...I checked it

Comment: Did you try it though?

Comment: Try this to catch what's happen at the time when the onclick handler it attached: `for (var i = 0; i <document.links.length; i++) { var _link = document.links[i]; if (_link.href.substr(_link.href.length - 4) == ".pdf") {debugger;} ...}` then adding on the attachment of the handler. This will call the debugger when the handler is attaching to a pdf link so you can step through and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the href attribute and do the redirect to the file in the catch function. Do some logic and then redirect the user to the new page/file.

```
<a id="pdf" href="">tmp.pdf</a>

for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) { 
    document.links[i].onclick = function() { 
           doSomething();  
           if(link[s].id == "pdf"){
               window.location="tmp.pdf";
           }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: thank you for response but i don't know about pdf name in javascript. it is html provided by server to me

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make sure, you're javascript executing after page load. it may works for you

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
  document.links[i].onclick = function() {
         alert('testing')
      }
  }
});
```

FYI, i'm using jQuery ready event to make sure script executes after page load.

Comment: The op requested no JQuery. Otherwise I'd agree.

Comment: i tried it via jQuery as well. also this solution. Result is the same, normal hyperlinks are called but 'pdf' hyperlinks not.

Comment: I'm not sure about you're issue, but you can debug with event.preventDefault()

Comment: maybe i have there some another code that cause this problem. because it is big existing page. i have to explore it more. thank you very much

Comment: @y0io great, you could try window.onload, if you don't want to use jQuery

Answer (score 0):

so, i found it...somewhere in javascript files i found this code that causes my problem

```
  if ( (String($(this).prop('href')).indexOf('.pdf') != -1)) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.cancelBubble = true;
```

thanks